# Is there a lingustic term for okurigana omission?

Tags: terminology, okurigana

Is there a (Japanese) linguistic term for okurigana omission (cases when 問い合わせ is written as 問合せ, etc.)?  If not then what would be a concise way to refer to the phenomena (in Japanese)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a non-linguist, I have no idea if this term is used in linguistics, but our 文化庁{ぶんかちょう} (Agency for Cultural Affairs) calls it 「許容{きょよう}」 ("tolerance").

http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kakuki/10/tosin01/02.html

To refer to the phenomenon, you could use a phrase like:

「誤読{ごどく}の可能性{かのうせい}が低{ひく}い（単{たん}）語{ご}の送{おく}り仮名{がな}の省略{しょうりゃく}」

That would be understood by all native-speakers, I promise.

Comment: Even shorter, perhaps just 送{おく}り仮名{がな}の省略{しょうりゃく}.

Answer (score 2):

The word 送る seen in *okurigana* (送り仮名) is the term to mean "put okurigana".

For example you could say:

> 「問い合わせ」の「せ」だけ送る (you'll get 問合せ)
>
> 「申し込み」の「し」は送らない (you'll get 申込み)
>
> 「終わる」は「わる」と送る (you'll get 終わる instead of 終る)